Bug in translation system: load_theme_textdomain() returns true, files are available and accessible but the language defaults to english
Looks like this has been introduced in WordPress 6.7 - I have the following code:
$loaded = load_theme_textdomain(MY_TEXTDOMAIN,get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages'); // internationalization

$locale = get_locale();

The locale is correct and available, load_them_textdomain() returns true but the language in the theme is English instead of German in this case.
Using de_DE_formal for the project. Did anyone experience a similar issue? How can it fail though the language is correctly loaded and set? Help would be really appreciated.

have you tried the translation call just after the call to get_locale ?

have you checked the WP Trac for a bug ticket? Note that this isn't a discussion forum it's a question answer site, you need to phrase your question so that someone would have to write an answer that you can mark as correct, not just a reply

@mmm Good point. The translation call fails directly after the get_locale unfortunately.

The comment of Tom J Nowell has pointed me into the correct direction here it looks like this is really WordPress bug: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/62337
